# Select column where is value null or zero

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have this [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VYKH.png) and i want to increment column cell's value by one, where is value null or 0 to 5. When value in cell is 6, i want to incement by one next column. And repeat. When every column's value  in row is 6, i need go to next row and do same actions. For example: I update column 01 on first row, add 1. Next query, add 1,.. When value is 6, I need do same things with column 02... What is the best way? Thanks

This db is database of storage, every cell value represents how much boxes are in this position

[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Hlda.png)

[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EnUE.png)

```
CREATE TABLE `ciselnik_sklad_regal_pozice` (
 `REGAL` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `POLICE` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
 `POZICE` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
 `01` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
 `02` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
 `03` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
 `04` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
 `05` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
 `06` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
 `07` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
 `08` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
 `09` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
 `10` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
 `11` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
 `12` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
 `13` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
 `14` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
 `15` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
 `16` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
 `17` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
 `18` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
 `19` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
 `20` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
 `21` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
 `22` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
 `23` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
 `24` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
 `25` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
 `26` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
 `27` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
 `28` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
 `29` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
 `30` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
 `31` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
 `32` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
 `33` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
 `34` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
 `35` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
 `36` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
 `37` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
 `38` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
 `39` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
 `40` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Show a couple of lines and the expected result. A few columns will suffice (no need to show them all).

Comment: I don't have code for this.

Comment: I meant a couple of lines of data, **before** and **after** the change you want.

Comment: Sorry. There are images before and after 22 queries, which increment value in cell by one.

Comment: FYI\, instead of images, please paste text and mark as code. We can't copy/paste from an image when trying to duplicate or troubleshoot. Thanks

Comment: @SloanThrasher Sorry, here you are.

Comment: Hi Adam, if you're storing numbers in the columns `01`,`02`, etc., why are the not integer instead of varchar?

Comment: @SloanThrasher i dont know, because i didnt create this one :) I got a finished database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```
UPDATE TestTable SET 
`01` = CASE WHEN `01` < 6 THEN `01`+1 ELSE `01` END,
`02` = CASE WHEN `01` = 6 AND `02` < 6 THEN `02`+1 ELSE `02` END,
`03` = CASE WHEN `02` = 6 AND `03` < 6 THEN `03`+1 ELSE `03` END,
`04` = CASE WHEN `03` = 6 AND `04` < 6 THEN `04`+1 ELSE `04` END,
`05` = CASE WHEN `04` = 6 AND `05` < 6 THEN `05`+1 ELSE `05` END,
`06` = CASE WHEN `05` = 6 AND `06` < 6 THEN `06`+1 ELSE `06` END,
`07` = CASE WHEN `06` = 6 AND `07` < 6 THEN `07`+1 ELSE `07` END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to so this with a single query. Add a where clause if needed.

```
UPDATE `table`
SET `01` = if(`01` >= 6,6,`01`+1),
    `02` = if(`02` >= 6,6,if(`01` = 6 AND COALESCE(`01`,0) => 0,`02`+1,`02`)),
    `03` = if(`03` >= 6,6,if(`02` = 6 AND COALESCE(`02`,0) => 0,`03`+1,`03`)),
    etc...
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but it seems the OP wants to update the next column based not on the original value of this column, but on the resulting one. That's not usually possible. I may be wrong.

Comment: If previsou column's value is six, i need increment next column by one, else increment previous column by one.

Comment: This db is database of storage, every cell value represents how much boxes are in this position.